# Genymotion Not starting up on mac

Tags: android, genymotion

My Genymotion suddenly stops work. I tried by update the host ip and reinstalled genymotion, virtual box every thing. But still geny motion is not working for me. Its hangs and keeps on loading for 3 mins. At the end I am getting error as "Unable to connect to the virtual device. Genymotion will now close. Please check VirtualBox network configuration" . Is any one faced the same issue earlier?

Answer (score 4):

Let's try a clean run :

- Close all Genymotion windows
- Open VirtualBox > General Settings (top bar) > Network tab > Host-Only Network tab > remove ALL the interface listed
- Relaunch a Genymotion device

If it is not working, please extract the logs (from the settings) and send a message to the support.

Answer (score 1):

You have to **Discard** the machines in **VirtualBox** to shutdown the state of machine